# Error: expected unqualified id and primary-expression message

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am relatively new to coding and having some trouble with getting this code to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BBoard.hpp"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

Board::Board()
{
    board = new bool*[10];
    ship = new Ship**[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        board[i] = new bool[10];
        ship[i] = new Ship*[10]; 
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = false;
            ship[i][j] = nullptr;
        }
    unsunkShipCount = 0;
}

bool** Board::getAttackArray(){return board;}

Ship***Board::getShipArray(){return ship;}

int Board::getNumShipsRemain(){return unsunkShipCount;}

bool Board::placeShip(Ship ship, int row, int col, char coord)
{
    if(coord == 'R')
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < ship.getLength(); i++)
        {
            if(col+i >= 10)
                return false;
            if(Ship[row][col+i] != nullptr)
                return false;
            Ship[row][col+i] = &ship;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < ship.getLength(); i++)
        {
            if(row+i >= 10)
                return false;
            if(Ship[row+i][col] != nullptr)
                return false;
            Ship[row+i][col] = &ship;
        }
    }
    unsunkShipCount++;
    return true;
}

bool Board::attack(int row, int col)
{
    if(ship[row][col] == nullptr)
    {
        board[row][col] = true;
        return false;
    }
    if(board[row][col] ==false)
    {
        ship[row][col] -> takeHit();
        board[row][col] = true;
    }
    if(ship[row][col] -> getDamage() == ship[row][col] -> getLength())
    {
        cout << "They sank " << ship[row][col] -> getName() << endl;
        unsunkShipCount--;
    }
    return true;
}

bool Board::allShipsSunk()
{
    return unsunkShipCount == 0;
}
```

I am tasked with creating a board class that can be used for a Battleship game. I keep receiving these messages when trying to compile:

> error: expected primary-expression before '[' token

On lines 36 and 47.  As well as:

> error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token

On lines 38 and 49.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: why are you using row pointers? why cann't you make it with `std::vector<std::vector<>>` ?

Comment: A good start would be to stop allocating things with `new`

Comment: You are mixing up the type name `Ship` and the member variable `ship`. Instead of `if(Ship[row][col+i] != nullptr)`. you need to use `if(ship[row][col+i] != nullptr)`. Make similar changes where you are using `Ship[][]`.

Comment: Voting to close for typo.

Comment: That was a fast response, appreciate it my peeps. Now I'm getting this message "error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Ship' and 'int')" on all four lines mentioned.

Comment: This is after changing "Ship" to "ship".

Comment: FYI, `Board::placeShip()` is storing a pointer to a temporary `Ship` object that goes out of scope when `placeShip()` exits, leaving the array with a dangling pointer to invalid memory. The `ship` parameter needs to be passed by reference instead of by value: `Ship &ship`. And why are you using so much pointer indirection in this code? I mean, 3 levels of indirection, really? Your arrays are small and fixed-sized, so you shouldn't be using `new[]` at all. Declare the `board` member as simply `bool board[10][10];` and the `ship` member as `Ship* ship[10][10];`, no dynamic allocation needed.